# Updating table with self referencing window query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm having an issue with trying to update a table with a self referencing subquery in Oracle SQL Developer. I believe I have the query set up correctly however I'm getting a generic 'missing right parenthesis' error whenever I try to run it despite all parentheses matching up properly.

In short I'm trying to update a transactional sequence column based on a ROW_NUMBER() function partitioned over values inside the table I'm trying to update. I've set up a query to subquery the partitioned window and update the table based off the rownum.

Is there a way I can re-write this to get it working? I'm not sure what is throwing the parenthesis errorr.

````
update tbl a 
set transseq = (select sqtransseq from (select row_number() OVER(Partition by location order by rownum) as sqtransseq, rownum 
                from tbl ) as b
                where a.rownum = b.rownum)```
````

Comment: Please provide sample data, or at least the data structure of the table.

Comment: What the business rule is behind this update? Rowid is somewhat random: you may reorganize your table and will get new sequence. This is because SQL table is unordered set of rows, and Oracle do inserts in the available place, not to the "end" of the table.

Answer (score 1):

`rownum` does not do what you think.  I think you are confusing it with [`rowid`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm):

```
update tbl a 
    set transseq = (select sqtransseq
                    from (select t.*,
                                 row_number() OVER(Partition by location order by location) as sqtransseq 
                          from tbl t
                         ) b
                    where a.rowid = b.rowid
                   );
```

However, that does not work, because `rowid` is not allowed with window functions.  You can make this work using a hack of converting the `rowid` to a string:

```
update tbl a 
    set transseq = (select sqtransseq
                    from (select t.*, rowidtochar(rowid) as rowid_str,
                                 row_number() over (Partition by location order by location) as sqtransseq 
                          from tbl t
                         ) b
                    where rowidtochar(a.rowid) = b.rowid_str
                   );
```

Or phrase the logic differently:

```
update tbl a 
    set transseq = (select count(*)
                    from tbl b
                    where b.location = a.location and b.rowid <= a.rowid
                   );
```

Comment: Thanks, that last query worked like a charm! I tried re-writing to fit the second query you posted but kept getting a missing expression error.

Comment: @coterboat . . . Here is an example of the second query:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=269f024eb1d60e48d7d2941176c59de3.

Comment: Ordering by rowid makes no sense

Comment: @astentx . . . Nothing in answer ordered by `rowid`.  I assume you mean `order by rownum` which was just taken from the OP.  The ordering appears to be irrelevant, but the `order by` clause is needed.  I changed that to `location`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The last query: `... and b.rowid <= a.rowid`. I mean that the query itself (original intent and your working code) produce quite random order independent on data (depends on physical storage or query execution, which returns row in *some* indefinite order without `order by`). Updated query will also return unstable order because of `partition by` and `order by` are the same. I understand, that this is because the business rule was not clearly declared

Comment: @astentx . . . The ordering is arbitrary.  `rowid` is just being used as a unique id not for any "special" ordering.  The use of `rownum` in the original query suggests that the OP doesn't care about *what* the ordering is and only wants unique numbers.